# Nuclear spectral theorem in Rigged Hilbert Spaces (Gelfand-Maurin theorem)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, resource-recommendations, mathematical-physics

Before I go into the question, I would like to mention that **I am a physicist** with some formal mathematical knowledge, but not expert in functional analysis.

In physics, we very often say: Let $|x \rangle$ be the position basis, let $| p \rangle$ be the momentum basis. We then proceed to say $\langle x| x' \rangle= \delta(x-x')$ and similarly up to some factor for the momentum. They are related by the Fourier transform $\langle x |p \rangle=e^{ipx}$. Strictly speaking, this cannot be correct, as the "eigenfunctions" of the position and momentum operator are not elements of the Hilbert space, they are not square integrable. One could say, the set of eigenvectors in $H$ is empty.

I would like to give this a precise mathematical meaning and relate this to the spectrum. I am fully aware of the very fact which is pointed out in mathematical physics texts, such as Simon-Reed, or Moretti, that what we ultimately measure is the spectrum and that can be read off simply from the spectral theorem without any referrence to eigenvectors. So strictly speaking to do this, is not a necessity, and QM is complete even without this. However, if physicists use this, I am confident that this can be made precise! :)

After long search, I found out that the language physicists use can be made precise in the Rigged Hilbert space setting. This precisely means that we choose a dense subspace of $H$ and take its topological dual, and embed $H$ into the dual. Then we can make sense of "position and momentum eigenkets" as elements of this topological dual. Now, what I would like to see:

1. Let $A$ be a self-adjoint (possibly unbounded) operator on $H$. Then corresponding to the purely continuous spectrum, there are no eigenvectors of $A$ in $H$, but there exist generalized eigenvectors of $A$ in the topological dual of the dense subspace.
2. [the spectral theorem in this nuclear setting](https://www.mdpi.com/2075-1680/8/3/89#:%7E:text=Theorem%201.,1) (theorem 1 in the link), or in more concrete terms: Let $A$ be a self-adjoint operator on an infinite dimensional separable Hilbert space $H$ with simple absolutely continuous spectrum $\sigma(A)=\mathbb{R}^{+}$. Then, there exists a Rigged Hilbert space $\phi \subset H \subset \phi^{\times}$, such that

- a) $A \phi \subset \phi$ and $A$ is continuous on $\phi$. Therefore it may be continuously extented to $\phi^{\times}$.
- b) For almost all $\omega \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$, with respect to the Lebesgue measure, there exists $| \omega \rangle \in \phi^{\times}$ so that $A | \omega \rangle=\omega | \omega \rangle$.
- c) For any pair of vectors $\varphi,\psi \in \phi$, and any measurable function $f:\mathbb{R}^{+} \to \mathbb{C}$, we have that $$\langle \varphi| f(A) \psi \rangle= \int_{0}^{\infty} f(\omega) \langle \varphi | \omega \rangle \langle \omega| \psi \rangle d \omega,$$ with $\langle \omega|\psi \rangle^{*}=\langle \psi | \omega \rangle$.
- d) The above spectral decomposition is implemented by a unitary operator $U:H \to L^2(\mathbb{R}^{+})$, with $U (\psi)=\langle \omega| \psi \rangle=\psi(\omega)$ and $(U A U)^{-1} \psi(\omega)=\omega \psi(\omega)=\omega \langle \omega| \psi \rangle$ for any $\psi \in \phi$. This means that $UAU^{-1}$ is the multiplication operator on $U \psi$.
- e) For any pre existent Rigged Hilbert space $\phi \subset H \subset \phi^{\times}$, such that $A \phi \subset \phi$ with continuity and $A$ is satisfying our hypotheses, then items $b)-d)$ hold.

I haven't seen a proof of 1), but the statement can be found in Frederic Schuller's [lecture notes](https://docs.wixstatic.com/ugd/6b203f_a94140db21404ae69fd8b367d9fcd360.pdf), page 191, proposition 20.2.

For the second, 2) I have seen four proofs in the literature, which partly prove it, but none fully and  none of them is followable/student-friendly. One is in [Blanchard's  mathematical physics book](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-14045-2), and the second proof is in [Maurin's book](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/General-eigenfunction-expansions-and-unitary-of-Maurin/253410554357999b922e45557f8b02d0c77328c9), the third being in an article by Gould. The fourth proof (original by Maurin,Gelfand) [seems to be incorrect](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/179932/error-in-maurins-proof-for-the-nuclear-spectral-theorem), and [is pointed out in the translation of the book](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/proof-of-gelfand-maurin-nuclear-spectral-theorem.294488/).

So my question is: can anyone recommend *student-friendly* sources (say, starting from functional analysis as covered by Moretti's book on Spectral theory and QM, or Frederic Schuller's lectures),   which prove these two theorems? I am aware that this might probably be hard to find, but in case there is no other literature than I provided, can perhaps some expert in the field direct me to what prerequisites should I learn/where can I find the material that I need to write myself a self-contained proof following one of the proofs in the literature?

P.S. According to the nuclear theorem part e), is the Schwartz space subset Hilbert space subset space of tempered distributions the **unique up to unitary equivalence of Gelfand triples** Rigged Hilbert space, which makes the construction in physics work?

Comment: If $|x\rangle$ is just a position basis, what is Planck's constant doing in the inner product? What is the physics behind having Planck's constant there?

Comment: Nothing, you are right. I did a mistake, which is now corrected. What I really meant is that in physics we write things like $\langle x| P_x | \psi \rangle=-i h \frac{d}{dx}  \langle x| \psi \rangle= -h \frac{d}{dx} \psi(x)$.

Comment: Concerning my book: I do not prove anything about the Gelfand approach. In my research work I use it to produce formal identities and finally I prove them by using the standard (von Neumann's) approach. My personal opinion is that Gelfand's approach is too cumbersome to be used in the practice. It is much better to use formal arguments in terms of bra-ket Dirac's notations and finally to make rigorous everything exploiting the von Neumann mathematical machinery.

Comment: Dear Valter, thank you for your response. Yes, I know that in your book this formalism is not mentioned in formal sense, and I do agree with you that it is probably ineffective in practice,as it gets cumbersome. However, I think (from a mathematical physics perspective), it would be nice to fully clarify it once and for all, that what we use in physics can be formalized in the language we use it (not just von Neumann machinery). I would personally not work in this formalism myself either, but I would enjoy going through it once. This is just a matter of my personal taste perhaps. :D